# Find customer ids who ordered more in 2019 than they did in 2018

Tags: sql, oracle

This one was asked in an interview.

Below is the structure of the table.

```
Shipments- Shipment_id,Price, Order_id, Ship_date, Delivery_Location, Price, Ship_method , ShipETA,
Customer-Customer_id, order_id, customer_address, prime_eligible
Order - Order_id , Order_Qty, Order_date , Order_location, Item_id , Shipment_id
Item- Item _id , Item_description, Item_Location
```

Question: List of customer ids who ordered more in 2019 than they did in 2018.

```
    SELECT customer_id
FROM Customer join Order using (order_id)
WHERE YEAR(Order_date) IN (2019)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Order_date) = 2019 THEN Order_Qty ELSE 0 END)
    >  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(Order_date) = 2018 THEN Order_Qty ELSE 0 END)
```

Unfortunately, I don't have sample data can anyone help with the approach to solve this one.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, sum case etc

Comment: yeah just stuck with the approach of how to do compare year by year and list user as I am new to SQL any sample query will be great help.

Comment: Some effort required here. Make it easy to assist you, make up some data and find out the expected result. [mcve]

Comment: Also, different products have different sets of SQL functionality - which one do you want an answer for?

Comment: Sure I will set up sample data and post it here soon. It was for the Oracle database question.

Comment: What happens if try `WHERE YEAR(Order_date) IN (2018, 2019)`?

Answer (score 0):

Data model you posted looks somewhat "strange"; I wouldn't keep `ORDER_ID` in `CUSTOMER` table, it just doesn't belong there. I'd add `CUSTOMER_ID` into `SHIPMENT` instead.

Anyway, here's one option:

- sample data in lines #1 - 21
- `temp` CTE calculates summaries (ordered quantities) per customers and years (just or 2018 and 2019)
- final query just checks who ordered more items in 2019 than in 2018

---

```
SQL> with
  2  customer (customer_id, order_id) as
  3    (select 'A', 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'A', 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'B', 2 from dual union all
  6     select 'B', 4 from dual union all
  7     select 'B', 5 from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 'A', 6 from dual
 10    ),
 11  orders (order_id, order_qty, order_date) as
 12    -- A's summaries: 2018: 100 / 2019: 400
 13    -- B's summaries: 2018: 400 / 2019: 300  --> should be returned
 14    (select 1, 100, date '2018-05-03' from dual union all -- A
 15     select 2, 200, date '2018-07-23' from dual union all -- B
 16     select 3, 400, date '2019-04-02' from dual union all -- A
 17     select 4, 300, date '2019-08-14' from dual union all -- B
 18     select 5, 200, date '2018-11-14' from dual union all -- B
 19     --
 20     select 6, 900, date '2020-01-01' from dual           -- A
 21    ),
 22  -- summaires per customers and years
```

---

```
 23  temp as
 24    (select c.customer_id,
 25       extract(year from o.order_date) as year,
 26       sum(o.order_qty) sum_qty
 27     from customer c join orders o on o.order_id = c.order_id
 28     where extract(year from o.order_date) in (2018, 2019)
 29     group by c.customer_id,
 30              extract(year from o.order_date)
 31    )
 32  select t.customer_id
 33  from temp t
 34  group by t.customer_id
 35  having sum(case when t.year = 2019 then t.sum_qty end) <
 36         sum(case when t.year = 2018 then t.sum_qty end);

CUSTOMER_ID
-----------
B

SQL>
```